# Pillow not loadng image from local system - No such file or directory: 'home/hp/DeepLearning/images/picasso.jpg'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, python-imaging-library, ubuntu-18.04

```
imsize = 512 if torch.cuda.is_available() else 128 

loader = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(imsize),transforms.ToTensor()])

def image_loader(image_name):
    image = Image.open(image_name)
    image = loader(image).unsqueeze(0)
    return image.to(device, torch.float)
style_img = image_loader("home/hp/DeepLearning/images/picasso.jpg")
content_img = image_loader("home/hp/DeepLearning/images/picasso.jpg")
assert style_img.size() == content_img.size(),\"we need to import style and content images of the same size"
```

When I am trying to load image from my local system,it is showing me error. I have tried `os.path.abspath()`

Comment: Are you sure the file system path is correct? `home/hp/DeepLearning/images/picasso.jpg` seems like it would need a leading slash. Ex: `/home/hp/DeepLearning/images/picasso.jpg`